# How can I get rows from a table that matches all the foreign keys from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have two tables role and roleApp defined like this:

```
create table #tempRole(roleId int);

insert into #tempRole (roleId) values (1)
insert into #tempRole (roleId) values (2)

create table #tempRoleApp(roleId int, appId int);

insert into #tempRoleApp (roleId, appId) values (1, 26)
insert into #tempRoleApp (roleId, appId) values (2, 26)
insert into #tempRoleApp (roleId, appId) values (1, 27)
```

So, from #tempRoleApp table, I want to get only the rows that matches all the values of the #tempRole table (1 and 2), so in this case the output needs to be 26 (as it matches both 1 and 2) but not 27 as the table does not have 2, 27).

#tempRole table is actually the output from another query so it can have arbitrary number of values.

I tried few things like:

```
select *
from #tempRoleApp
where roleId = ALL(select roleId FROM #tempRole)
```

Which does not give anything... tried few more things but not getting what I want.

Comment: `select ra.appId from #tempRoleApp ra inner join #tempRole r on r.roleId = ra.roleId group by ra.appId having count(*) = (select count(*) from #tempRole)`; Use a left join if "extra" roles are possible that should then be excluded as identical matches.

Comment: @shawnt00: Yes in this case this works but say I add one more role in the table insert into #tempRole (roleId) values (3), then it should not return any values but the above query gives 26, 27, tried left join too with the same result

Comment: Update your post with all possible corner cases, and make the expected output explicit, formatted as a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this gives what you were looking for.

```sql
select tra.appId
from #tempRoleApp as tra
join #tempRole as tr on tra.roleId = tr.roleId
group by tra.appId
having count(distinct tra.roleId) = (select count(distinct roleId) from #tempRole)
```

It uses `count distinct` to get the total unique roleId's in the tempRole table and compares that with the unique count of these per appId, after confirming the roleIds match between the tables.

As you clarified in the comment, once you add another tempRole roleId, now no entry has all of the Ids so no rows are returned.

Comment: This query is slightly more precise than shawnt's one (because of the first distinct - the second one is not needed), nonetheless both return the same output with or without the update that OP suggested on the #temprole input table.

Comment: Indeed, I came up with almost the same answer independently, then must've made a mistake during testing that made it look like shawnt's query had a different result. Perhaps OP made a similar error noting in comment  "...then it should not return any values but..." - well indeed neither query returns any values after the insert, which seems like the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes this takes care of all boundary conditions I tested

Comment: When all ids remain distinct what purpose does that condition then serve?

Comment: @shawnt00 Nothing, more just a safeguard against duplicated data on either side potentially confounding the result. If there are means in place to prevent this, they can be omitted. It was only due to said mistake in testing that I submitted this, assuming I must've done something fundamentally different.